# Synchronizing two looping HTML5 videos

Tags: html, video, synchronization

I have two MP4 videos running with the HTML5 video tag.

```
<video width="640" height="480" loop>
   <source src="a.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<video width="640" height="480" loop>
   <source src="a.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

The two videos are identical so they have the exactly same number of frames and the same frame rate. Even I force them to start at the same time, they get out of synchronization over time. Is there any way to synchronize both videos? Even animated GIF is fine if it can be synchronized.